# select function windows vs linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

i've the following code which runs just fine under windows env while in linux using the same code it doesn't (besides few changes of libs) .the select function does not respond to new connections.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
struct SocketState
{
    int id;         // Socket handle 
    int recv;           // Receiving?
    int send;           // Sending?
    int sendSubType;    // Sending sub-type
    char buffer[128];
    int len;
    int authenticate;
    char userName[10];
};


struct SocketState sockets[MAX_SOCKETS]={0};

int socketsCount = 0;


int main() 
{


    int listenSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (-1 == listenSocket)
    {
        return 0 ;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverService;

    serverService.sin_family = AF_INET; 

    serverService.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    serverService.sin_port = htons(TIME_PORT);


    if (-1 == bind(listenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverService, sizeof(serverService))) 
    {
    perror("Couldn't bind socket");
        return -1;
    }


    if (-1 == listen(listenSocket, 10))
    {

        perror("Couldn't listen to port");      
    }

    addSocket(listenSocket, LISTEN);


        while (true)
    {

        fd_set waitRecv;
        FD_ZERO(&waitRecv);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS; i++)
        {
            if ((sockets[i].recv == LISTEN) || (sockets[i].recv == RECEIVE))
                FD_SET(sockets[i].id, &waitRecv);
        }

        fd_set waitSend;
        FD_ZERO(&waitSend);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS; i++)
        {
            if (sockets[i].send == SEND)
                FD_SET(sockets[i].id, &waitSend);
        }


        int nfd;
        nfd = select(0, &waitRecv, &waitSend, NULL, NULL);
        if (nfd == -1)
        {

            return 0 ;
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `0` as the first argument to `select`. That is wrong. Probably in Windows this parameter is not used, but in linux it have to be set correctly.

It has to be set to the number of the higher `fd` plus 1.

Comment: tnx, i read that before and it does not help when i called again to select() at the next iteration . i used the macro FD_SETSIZE which solves the issue.